# Vagrant Private Networks permissions

Tags: networking, vagrant

I'm setting up Vagrant on a university network. I don't want to use a public network as the university network is quite strict about what can connect. I'd rather use a private network.

The problem is, when using a private network Vagrant seems to create a network adapter on the machines, something the students don't have permission to do. Is there any way to set up the private network in such a way that it doesn't require administrator privileges on the machine?

The machines are running Windows 7, and the vagrant box is using Virtual Box with a Linux guest.

Comment: what is the issue if you leave a default bridge network ? why do you want the VM to have private IP ?

Comment: The university locks down what it allows to connect to the network so I can't use a public network. I need to use private, but can't seem to do that without needing an admin password to create the adapter